# Question that is a no-brainer

Tags: word-choice, word-formation, word-phrases

I need a phrase which has a meaning of **a question that is very easy to answer and requires very little thought**. I think it might have something to do with word **no-brainer**.

I don't know if **a no-brainer question** is grammatically correct since both are nouns.

Is it actually correct or not? Is there any alternative?

Comment: "No-brainer" is a noun, and does not require "question" to follow if the meaning is clear in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with "no-brainer question".

A [compound noun](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/compnounterm.htm) is a noun that is composed of two or more nouns. When there are two nouns like "no-brainer question", the first noun functions as a [noun modifier](http://www.onestopenglish.com/grammar/grammar-reference/adjectives/adjectives-and-noun-modifiers-in-english-article/144843.article).

Another broadly used idiom is "[rocket science](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rocket-science)" which means:

> an activity requiring considerable intelligence and ability (esp in the phrase **not exactly rocket science**)

[Dictionary.com]

If you say "This isn't a rocket science question", it means it is no-brainer.

Comment: Good answer but personally I would expect a question that's "Not rocket science" to still require a little more thought than a "no-brainer".  Like "no-brainer" is a 1 on the difficulty scale, and "not rocket science" is a 3 perhaps, out of 10 that is.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to apply [self-evident](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-evident) here.

> Not needing to be demonstrated or explained; obvious:
>   *self-evident truths*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/self-evident

Comment: I don't think that most no-brainer questions are self evident.  If you asked me my favourite film I'd say "That's a no brainer - 2001 A Space Odyssey!".  That's in no way self-evident though, even to people who know me.

Comment: Indeed a no-brainer for the questioner is different from a no-brainer for the answerer.